# Where's the best place to begin to master Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I just want to know where to learn all the commands and all the internet tools and protocols and whatever. Please don't tell me MAN because that's written for robots.

Comment: For documention on the command-line see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168142/are-there-any-tutorials-and-books-to-get-accustomed-to-the-terminal) and for Ubuntu and the filesystem, see [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165677/which-book-should-i-buy-to-learn-file-system-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Not to be a robot about it, but you could try the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/index.html).

Sure, it's a lot, but you want to learn everything. ALL the commands, even the protocols.

I'd say you might just want to boot it and start using it, and if you come across something you don't understand, ask it here. And yes, if you don't understand a command, like for instance `ls`, the MAN page is still the page to check.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these free ebooks: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/free-ubuntu-linux-e-books.html

Answer (score 0):

Google is still your best friend.  The man pages will make more sense when you get used to the layout - they should still be used as the definitive source of information.

Do a google search for bash tutorials and primers.  There's often good articles on sites like [Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/) and [OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/).  To add one I haven't seen recommended anywhere else  (maybe because it's a commercial effort) is [Linux Format](http://www.linuxformat.com/) but I've seen some top bash tutorials and how-to articles published in its pages.

Answer (score 0):

To begin mastering Ubuntu, master the base, the source, i.e. Linux. I'd refer [**Complete Reference Linux**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0078824613). It covers majority of the aspects. To start from the very basics and to get a detailed grasp of Ubuntu, refer [**Linux for Dummies**](http://www.dummies.com/store/Computers-Internet/Operating-Systems/Linux.html) (don't go on the title, it can be the start you are looking for).

Also worth taking a look :

[Ubuntu Unleashed 2012](http://www.flipkart.com/ubuntu-unleashed-2012-0672335786/p/itmd32yhsnskjkvs?pid=9780672335785&query=0672335786), covering 11.10 and 112.04.
[A Practical Guide to Ubuntu Linux.](http://www.flipkart.com/practical-guide-ubuntu-linux-with-cdrom-013254248x/p/itmczyqhkbhss5fc?pid=9780132542487&query=013254248X)

Answer (score 0):

Acording to OMGUbuntu, it's "Ubuntu Made Easy"

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/ubuntu-made-easy-book-review

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the use of the command line in Linux, Ubuntu included, then a good introduction that is available both as a printed book as well as a free creative commons released ebook is [The Linux Command Line by William E. Shotts, Jr.](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)

I do agree that the man pages are often fairly cryptic but as you use the command line more you will likely become more comfortable with tapping them; and since they are unlikely to be rewritten overnight, they are still a very good resource to use when you need to look up the details of using a command or it's flags.

Answer (score 0):

I am COMPLETELY new to Linux and I am finding this post on [techradar.pro](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/beginner-s-guide-to-linux-where-to-start-1066778) quite insightful...by the way - I find absolutely everything I need to know about anything via Google, including the post I am suggesting now

Answer (score 0):

Well, life is no cockaigne ... try terms in google like :

> free bash tutorial linux for beginners

And you have all freedom to search for a suiting free book.

Here are some openbooks (in German) :

http://galileocomputing.de/openbook